# Android Studio disable line wrap

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this strange line wrap on Android Studio and I want to disable because it freaks me out...

[image]

Comment: almost all the helpers in android studio freak me out.. :) thanks.. have removed all..

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In Android Studio 0.4.0 following should help:

```
Configure > Settings > Editor > Uncheck 'Use soft wraps in editor'
```

[image: Screenshot from Android Studio 0.4.0 Settings screen]

On Mac (Android Studio 3.0):

```
Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Uncheck 'Use soft wraps in editor'
```

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted the opposite.

Answer (score 63):

It's also available under the context menu
[image]

Comment: This helped me because softwarpp was enabled by system itself. So I dont have option to disable in settings. However this helped to solve the problem

Comment: Nice. This method now also allows you to enable/disable line wrap for just a single file which is nice if you want to wrap a specific text file or something and keep the others as is.

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to *entirely* disable wrapping and I found a workaround.

[image]

It doesn't seem to work for specific file extensions (Groovy, HTML, Java, etc.) but does with the general value. I set it with a significantly great number and am having no more wrapping.

I think they should give a master option for it!

Answer (score 9):

If you're wondering how to do this for Flutter/Dart, here's how:

1. File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Dart
2. Change the Line length field to something bigger than the default (I'm using 300)

[image]

This should work for any programming language.

Answer (score 7):

In Android Studio 2.3.3+, to disable line wrapping, you need to go to:

- Preferences

  - Code Styles

    - [Select a Language, e.g. Java]
    - Set "*wrap on typing*" to NO.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio 1.0.2, there is no menu named **Configure**. **Settings** is now under **File** menu. Everything are as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Right click near the line numbers for the soft wrap option to pop up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 3.5.3 you can set the soft wrap **to line up with the orginal lines indent** AND set an additional indent spaces. Makes it easier for me to read 
Settings --> Editor --> General

[image: settings screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found helpful that in the current version (Android Studio 3.2) you can set the **soft wrap** indicators to show only in the current line in adition to using soft wraps in editor.

Check the **Show soft wrap indicators for current line only** in:

`Editor -> General -> Soft Wraps`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is also the auto-line breaking issue, where AS will automatically add hard line returns in long lines. I found the setting for this in Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Hard wrap at [X] and []wrap on typing.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 4.1.3:

Preferences > Code Style > uncheck `wrap on typing`