# Android code format

Tags: java, android

Could you please help me on this?

I am using UBUNTU OS and with Android studio, unable to format my code it aligned as below. Can anyone sort this issue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried CONTROL+ALT+SHIFT+L but it doesn't worked.

Comment: Food for thoughts: by preventing people to post imgur links in questions, we would probably increase the overall site quality almost immediately...

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580171/code-formatting-shortcut-in-android-studio

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your formatting. Your lines are just wrapping around because you seem to be working on an ultra-low resolution. Hide the navigation tree on the left and you'll see everything pop into place.

Comment: In default key binding the format code shortcut is CTL+ALT+L.

Comment: See this doc https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts. `CTRL` + `ALT` + `I` of selected code.

Comment: The above answers not worked for me please sort this issue ASAP.

Comment: @AravindMani *"sort this issue ASAP"*? You seem to be under the mistaken assumption that we work for you or somehow owe you our efforts. Your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882044/android-studio-disable-line-wrap) and should be closed as such.

Comment: Sorry I am right. Now it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatting looks good, what you want is to have "soft wraps" not enabled. Search for "soft wraps" in your IDE settings, you can manage them on many different levels.

See [Android Studio disable line wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882044/android-studio-disable-line-wrap)

Comment: can you tell me how to enable soft wraps?

Comment: Didn't the accepted answer work for you?

Comment: Yes, it worked for me Thank you.